# Dataflow job status returns UNKNOWN always

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to get the current state of my job. The following is the code.

Job creation

```
 final DataflowPipelineJob job =DataflowPipelineRunner.fromOptions(configuration.getOptions())
                                  .run(pipe);
```

My code to get job state

```
DataflowPipelineJob job=new DataflowPipelineJob(Utils.getProjectId(), jobId, getDataflowClient());      
job.getState();
```

But it always throws the following warning

```
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.DataflowPipelineJob getState: There were problems getting current job status:     
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 404 OK
Not Found
at  

com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:145)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:321)
at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1049)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.DataflowPipelineJob.getState(DataflowPipelineJob.java:188)
at com.pwc.google.dataflow.factory.DataFlowFactory.getStatus(DataFlowFactory.java:89)
at com.pwc.google.dataflow.controllers.JobMonitor.doPost(JobMonitor.java:28)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:125)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:35)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.doFilter(JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.java:60)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:257)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:76)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:146)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:482)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:437)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:444)
at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:230)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:308)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:300)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:441)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:234)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

And it returns **UNKNOWN** as state.

Please help to fix this.

Comment: Are you using util.Transport.newDataflowClient() to create your client object?  If not, it might be misconfigured which could lead to 404s.

Comment: I not using that. I am using requestIntializer to get Dataflow client. Like this new Dataflow(TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, Utils.getRequestInitializer(DataflowScopes.all())). Could you please explain how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create your Dataflow client object like this:

```
DataflowPipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.create().as(DataflowPipelineOptions.class);
Dataflow client = com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.Transport.newDataflowClient(options);
```

This will initialize credentials properly and automatically handle retries.

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot. Is there any reason why Dataflow.Builder does not work?

Comment: It will work as long as you pass a credential into Dataflow.Builder.  You can do that by constructing the request initializer with "new RetryHttpRequestInitializer(options.getGcpCredential()))", and passing that in the the Builder constructor.